# Dropzone FormData not available in `sendingmultiple` event?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using this following event
http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-successmultiple

to attempt to loop through all the files in FileData and append some extra properties to them. FileData is empty when using sendingmultiple. It works when using regular sending event.

```
sendingmultiple: (files, xhr, formData) => {
        for(let o of formData.entries()) {
          console.log('testing 123', o);
          //FormData is empty when using `sendingmultiple` event.
        }
      }
```

files array shows 25 files while formData is empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`formData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) within your function

I have not tested this with `successMultiple`, below is my use case:

```
function init(dropzone) {
  dropzone.on('sending', (event, xhr, formData) => {
    formData.append('mimeType', event.type);
    formData.append('filename', event.name);
  });
}

const eventHandlers = {
  init,
  maxfilesexceeded: function(file) { // eslint-disable-line
    this.removeAllFiles();
    this.addFile(file);
  },
};
```